# Various multicolumn in a header of a table

Tags: multicolumn

I want to use `\multicolumn` in the header of this table, so instead of having e.g: 2007 twice, these two columns would be merged , and so on. However, when I tried to implement `\multicolumn` it did not work properly, it returns me each column separated:

This was the original code I had:

```
\begin{table*}                                                                                                                  
    \centering                                                                                                                  
    \caption{Data from 2007-2013}                                                                                                                   
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}                                                                                                                    
    \hline Years    &   2007    &   2007    &   2008    &   2008    &   2009    &   2009    &   2010    &   2010    &   2011    &   2011    &   2012    &   2012    &   2013    &   2013    \\ \hline
    WS or UP    &   WS  &   UP  &   WS  &   UP  &   WS  &   UP  &   WS  &   UP  &   WS  &   UP  &   WS  &   UP  &   WS  &   UP  \\ \hline
    USA &   17\%    &   17\%    &   19\%    &   19\%    &   16\%    &   16\%    &   16\%    &   16\%    &   14\%    &   14\%    &   15\%    &   15\%    &   15\%    &   15\%    \\ \hline
    Europe  &   17\%    &   17\%    &   19\%    &   19\%    &   16\%    &   16\%    &   16\%    &   16\%    &   14\%    &   14\%    &   15\%    &   15\%    &   15\%    &   15\%    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}                                                                                                                   
    \label{fig:data}                                                                                                                    
    \end{table*}
```

This is what I tried with `\multicolumn` with no success:

```
\begin{table*}                                                                                                                  
\centering                                                                                                                  
\caption{Data from 2007-2013}                                                                                                                   
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}                                                                                                                    
\toprule                                                                                                                    
{}  &    \multicolumn{2}{c}{2007}           &    \multicolumn{2}{c}{2008}           &    \multicolumn{2}{c}{2009}           &    \multicolumn{2}{c}{2010}           &    \multicolumn{2}{c}{2011}           &    \multicolumn{2}{c}{2012}           &    \multicolumn{2}{c}{2013}           
\midrule                                                                                                                    
USA &   17\%    &   17\%    &   19\%    &   19\%    &   16\%    &   16\%    &   16\%    &   16\%    &   14\%    &   14\%    &   15\%    &   15\%    &   15\%    &   15\%    \\ \hline
Europe  &   17\%    &   17\%    &   19\%    &   19\%    &   16\%    &   16\%    &   16\%    &   16\%    &   14\%    &   14\%    &   15\%    &   15\%    &   15\%    &   15\%    \\ \hline
\bottomrule                                                                                                                 
\end{tabular}                                                                                                                   
\label{fig:data}                                                                                                                    
\end{table*}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a **full** [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: You need a line-break ``\\`` before `\midrule`. Also, you probably don't want the `\hline`s since you're using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1. You need `\\` before `\midrule`;
2. Don't use vertical rules when using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) mentions:

   > You will not go far wrong if you remember two simple guidelines at all times:
   >
   > 1. Never, ever use vertical rules.
   > 2. Never use double rules.
3. I'd also remove the intermediate `\hline`s.
4. With many similar column specifications, its more convenient to specify them using the notation `*{<num>}{<colspec>}`, which will repeat `<colspec>` a total of `<num>` times.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Data from 2007-2013}\label{fig:data}
  \begin{tabular}{*{15}{c}}
    \toprule
    {}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2007} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2008} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2009} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{2010} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2011} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2012}      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2013} \\
    \midrule
    USA    & 17\% & 17\% & 19\% & 19\% & 16\% & 16\% & 16\% & 16\% & 14\% & 14\% & 15\% & 15\% & 15\% & 15\% \\
    Europe & 17\% & 17\% & 19\% & 19\% & 16\% & 16\% & 16\% & 16\% & 14\% & 14\% & 15\% & 15\% & 15\% & 15\% \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should load the caption package, to have a correct vertical spacing between caption and table.

Comment: I would use an en-dash for the year range in the caption.

Comment: And I would save typing `\%` in each cell writing the tabular preamble as `{l*{14}{c<{\%}}}`.